# How to remove Items from ListView.Builder through onTap(){}

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I'm trying to remove items from the List using an onTap button which is not working.
I have created a container with - onTap(){viewImg.remove(index);}, but the images is not being removed like it should.
I believe it's an error in my code, if yes, please help me with this.
Here is the code:

```html
List<File> viewImg = List();

_imgFromGallery() async {
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      viewImg.add(image);
    });
  }


Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: viewImg.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return new SingleChildScrollView(
                          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                          child: Column(children: [
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              width: size.width * .8,
                              height: 149,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                image: FileImage(viewImg[index]),
                              )),
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  print('tapped');
                                  viewImg.remove(index);
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: size.width * .8,
                                height: 40,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Remove',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto Medium',
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ]),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the method removeAt for the position of the index. The remove removes where the object where is equal to.

Comment: So basically I should do this right?
viewImg.removeAt(index);

Comment: Yes, that will remove the position you indicate in the list.